# Mule Munit Mock and Spy functionality

Tags: mule-studio, mule-esb, munit

we are observing a behavior where in the variables set in the "before-call" and "after-call" blocks of the spy munit processor are not being recognized in the actual mule flows. Is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MUnit message processors can only be used in MUnit tests, not in Mule flows.

Comment: Hi @aled, can you pls re-read my question? We are setting some variables in the munit spy code and trying to make sure the variable values are updated when the flow execution returns to mule flows. Apparently, i am thinking the value will be updated if we use the same variable name.

Comment: MUnit Spy is not meant to change values. You should use to validate assertions. As the documentation says: "If you set variables, attributes, or modify the payload inside a Spy, these changes won’t persist outside the processor."